# How to call C function from nodeJS

Tags: c, node.js

I have some C functions that I need to call frequently from nodeJS (less than 1 second time intervals). The C function takes in an argument and returns a value, which might be an int or an array.

It can be as simple as below:

```
int main() {
    int x = 2;
    return x;
}
```

And I need to get the value x in nodeJS and be able to do `console.log(x)`

I tried using `node-ffi`, but I read from the internet that it has a large overhead and is thus inefficient for frequent function calls.

I also considered writing addons but it seems very troublesome (with unfamiliar V8, C++ code and all that...)

And there is not much resources regarding integration between nodeJS and C (they are mostly nodeJS with C++)

Could somebody help shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: convert it to c++ ?

Comment: Use C++ Addons, refer https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: I can't do that because the C code is not written by me, and my task is to do the bridging between C and nodeJS

Comment: Never make performance decisions along the lines of "this is too inefficient" based on what you read on the internet: *measure*, and if it is too slow, then you can look for something faster. Your "less than one second time intervals" might be an *eternity* relative to the "large overhead" of that FFI library. Sometimes "large overhead" means microseconds on modern computers, because a few microseconds is large relative to a C function or JIT-compiler JS function which takes mere nanoseconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

change your c code to

```
// myProgram.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    puts("4");
    return 0;
}
```

compile it with gcc, in the same directory as your node file

```
$ gcc -o myProgram myProgram.c
```

in your node file, require exec()

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
```

and use it like so:

```
exec("./myProgram", (error, stdout, stderr) => console.log(stdout));
```

This works well, it spins up a new process every time.

If, on the other hand, you want to keep the child process running, and call a function in that code from node, you can do that like this:

```
// multiplyBy2.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int timesTwo(int x){
    return x*2;
}

int main(void){
  char buff[100];
  int input,output;
  while(1){
    gets(buff);
    input = atoi(buff);
    output = timesTwo(input);
    printf("%d", output);
    // you must flush stdout or else node will hang!
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

compile multiplyBy2.c and then:

```
// myNodeApp.js

const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const __delay__ = t => new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(), t))
const ch = spawn('./multiplyBy2')

var result=undefined;

ch.stdout.on("data",(data)=>{
    result = parseInt(data.toString())
})

async function multiplyBy2InC(num){
    ch.stdin.write(`${num}\n`)
    while(result==undefined)
      await __delay__(1)
    const output = result
    result = undefined
    return output
}

// now you could call it like this, it will print 20 to the console
multiplyBy2InC(10).then(r=>console.log(r))
```

Comment: why not moving the: "const output = result
    result = undefined
    return output"
to the callbak ? after     "result = parseInt(data.toString())", to avoid the while and await block ing code?

Comment: Worth noting that all of these solutions in this answer might have worse overhead than overhead of the FFI library the asker was worried about being too high.

Comment: -1 For not considering the OP's emphasize on efficiency and promoting use of exec which is a bad pattern for performance and security reasons. Not sure if connecting processes using stdin is a good practice either.

Comment: If you can show performance bottlenecks, or some problems with stdin, beyond feeling unsure, I will consider looking closer and modifying my answer. Many programs use stdin/out under the hood. How else would 2 processes communicate from user land?

Answer (score 0):

[One way to achieve this](https://www.karltarvas.com/how-to-call-a-c-or-cpp-function-from-node) is to use [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) to build a [Node addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Node kindly provides [a hello world addon demo](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/main/test/addons/hello-world) which we'll roughly follow below.

Firstly you'll need to [install `node-gyp`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation). When doing the initial setup, make sure you have [a compatible version of Python configured](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency). Next you'll need to provide a [`binding.gyp`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#the-bindinggyp-file), this file tells `node-gyp` how to build your project. A simple `binding.gyp` might look like this:

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "binding",
      "sources": [ "src/binding.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A barebones binding might look like the following. While it is written in C++, you can integrate your C code in much the same way. See [this article](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp) for some examples on how to mix C and C++.

```cpp
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

void Method(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
  v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello world").ToLocalChecked());
}

void init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports, v8::Local<v8::Object> module) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "foo", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, init);
```

Following that, you can run `node-gyp configure` to have `node-gyp` set up build tooling, and then `node-gyp build` to have it build your addon. If the output ends in `gyp info ok` then you've just successfully built your first native addon.

You can import your binding as any old module and use it in Node:

```js
const binding = require("./build/Release/binding");

console.log(binding.foo()); // Will log "hello world"
```

Answer (score -4):

Use a child process.
,.........
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback

Comment: Thanks, but I have two questions:
1. Do I need to write some code to end the created processes?
2. How to get the return value from the C function?