Call C pipe function from NodeJS
Does NodeJS have a way to call the C library pipe() function which creates two connected file descriptors?
Unfortunately this is really hard to google because Node has its own unrelated pipe() function.

would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266160/how-to-call-c-function-from-nodejs

No I'm looking for a built in function. I ended up searching the entire Node docs (handily available in a single page) for pipe and as far as I can see no such function exists.

Node's pipe function is in fact used to 'pipe' data from one stream into another. This can be used to transform data step-by-step or to read and write from one to another location. This seems to be quite what you are looking for. (Examples can be found all over the web, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169980/how-to-pipe-to-function-in-node-js) And if you mean exchanging shared state between processes then you might want to look up events: https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917

@geekhunger thanks for the attempt but that's not at all what I'm looking for. I am looking for the thing I asked for in the question.

Handily the Node docs are available in a single page which makes them quite easy to search despite the presence of lots of unrelated pipe features.
I looked through the entire page for v21.7.3 and unfortunately it doesn't expose the C pipe() function.
